# Where is the content of Program.cs stored after publishing a .Net Core web app?

Tags: c#, .net-core, publish

All DLLs, JSON files, wwwroot folders are reachable after publishing a .Net Core web app, but `Program.cs` isn't.

Is it safe to keep some user secrets in `Program.cs`? Or somehow 3rd persons can reach and read the content of `Program.cs`?

P.S. : I have decompiled my DLLs by JetBrains dotPeak application and reached controllers, methods, models that I wrote in my project, but there is nothing about the content of `Program.cs`.

Comment: So, what do you think happens with the code from Program.cs? Would a published application be able to run if its code weren't included?

Comment: @Zdenek Jelinek You are completely right. Because of this my title is "Where is the content of program.cs is storing after publish". I have checked published folder and couldn't find anything about the content of program.cs.

Comment: its best  to store these secrets with a service from your cloud service provider,for example Aws has [aws secrets manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/),Azure has [azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview).

Comment: @Denis Micheal Thanks for your advice. Im using azure keyvault in my projects, But it would be good to know is it secure to write some secrets in program.cs :)

Comment: If a bad actor gets access to your repo or a piece of your source code?, its not best practice to have these in code, don't forfeit security for convenience.

Comment: Yeah, so that implies that Program.cs is in no way special. Any host can load and run it which implies that the secret there is readable to anyone who gets hold of your deployment artifact or source code. So that means you have now a quite big surface that could leak - your local drive, network to upload artifact, drive of the server hosting your app. Possibly also all build servers, artifact storage servers, version control system and subsequently anyone ever who gets access there at ny point in the future. And of course, any network between any of those.

Comment: That being said, it really depends what "secure" means for you. Secure from what? If you use Azure Key Vault and then use it in a public-facing system that uses OpenSSL 1.0.1 (heartbleed), then that secret is not secure. You need to analyse what the risks are for your case and see whether that's acceptable. Most probably not unless you'll deploy a fresh secret every hour. But without knowledge of your context, the best we can offer is general practice which is **do not put secrets in your code**.

Comment: I suggest you do some basic research on how the .NET compiler works.

Answer (score 3):

The project containing `Program.cs` (note that it is not a requirement that this file has name `Program` but you need to provide an [entry-point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line) for the app) will be compiled into a dll/exe (by default it has the same name as the .csproj file but that is configurable).

Highly likely that you are using minimal hosting model with [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements) which will generate `Program` class with method named something like `<Main>$` ([sample @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoTB6bACAFwHsAHAWgBsBTANyorwGcCICqwqYC9MEUBOABQAiQDwbgEH3hASgDcQA=)), this class will contain the code you have written in the `Program.cs` file ([read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements#semantics), note that generational patterns can change, as they already did once since the feature introduction but there are parts of infrastructure provided by Microsoft that rely on the generated class name).

So to sum up: everything written in `Program.cs` will be available through process of decompilation and you should not store there any secrets.